# How to write conditional statement for a parameter between 2 values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a parameter d (distance):

20 <= **d**  < 60

[if  **d** between greater than or equal 20 , and less 60]

I'd like to know to represent this  in matlab?

Comment: just like the way you said it `d >= 20 & d <= 60` or just `20 <= d < 60`

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
if d>=20 && d<60
   %body
end
```

If `d` is a vector you can use `&` instead of `&&`

Comment: Thanks Haitham,  How about representing  if d between 20 to 60